# How to get select array empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The name of my select option property is populated dynamically.

On submit my form I need to know if all my forams selects filled ...

How can I do this?

I would also like to take the mouse cursor to the select that was not filled.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#teste").click(function () {


                a = $("select[name='sel[]'] option:selected").length;

                alert(a);

            });
        });
    </script>
<title>
</title>
</head>

    <form>
        <select name="sel[0]">
            <option value="teste"></option>
            <option value="teste">1234</option>
            <option value="teste">1234</option>
            <option value="teste">1234</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <select name="sel[1]">
            <option value="teste"></option>
            <option value="teste">1234</option>
            <option value="teste">1234</option>
            <option value="teste">1234</option>
        </select>

        ... Many others 
        <input type="button" id="teste" value="TESTAR">
    </form>

</html>
```

Comment: All the options have same value?

Comment: @PSL, No. My options no have same values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variable like this `var a;`.

There is no element with `select[name='sel[]']`, you have a number inside of it, you could use `name*=` or `name^=` to say name `contains` or name `starts with` `sel` respectively

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jgf3k/2/)***

```
$("#teste").click(function () {
    var a = $("select[name^='sel'] option:selected");
    var count = 0;
    $.each(a, function () {
        if ($(this).text().length) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    alert(count);
});
```

Comment: name^='sel' will be faster ;)

Comment: @Pedro - did you look at the DEMO? clicking button doesn't give you 2?

Comment: @Krishna - Yes. But when I select one option, receive 2. This is wrong for me.

Comment: @Pedro - wasn't clear in the question. edited my answer. check the demo now

Answer (score 1):

Give your default option a value of -1 and provide a common class name for these options(Which is efficient that attribute starts with selector).

Try:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select name="sel[0]" class="sel">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="teste">1234</option>
        <option value="teste">1234</option>
        <option value="teste">1234</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <select name="sel[1]" class="sel">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option value="teste">1234</option>
        <option value="teste">1234</option>
        <option value="teste">1234</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="teste" value="TESTAR">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#teste").click(function () {
          $(".sel").each(function () {
              if (this.value == -1) { //If you are not providing value check for this.selectedIndex == 0
                  $(this).focus(); //set the focus
                  return false; //and break out of the loop
             }
          });
      });
  });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLcqP/)**

Comment: Hi, I was trying the exact same solution, but for some reason `.focus().select()` seems not to work. can you tell me why? http://jsfiddle.net/ep98U/1/

Comment: sorry for the confusion, this is what I was actually working on. This time am inside loop, but element doesn't get focused, but your demo works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/ep98U/7/

Comment: @VenomVendor this.text and this.option.text are both different things... You cannot focus an option. You can focus only on a select. like this http://jsfiddle.net/cnft3/. Btw this question was asked by somebody else right :) ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution, actually I was trying to answer this question & ended up learning.

Comment: yup, you did help & +1'd  for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Select acts like the usual input when submitting form. So you can find selects with empty value:

```
$("select[value=]").first().focus()
```

Or iterate over all form elements, checking its value and type.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/UduNaGOh/1/edit?html,output

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#teste").click(function () {
      var test = true;     
      $("#myform select").each(function(){ 
        var select = $(this);
        if(select.val() == 'none') {
          select.addClass('fail');
          select.focus();
          test = false;
        } else {
          select.removeClass('fail');
        }
      });
      if(test){
        alert('well done');
        $("#myform select").removeClass('fail');
        // do your send stuff ...
      }
    });
  });
```

I'm changing the class to style the empty selects.
So here is the css:

```
#myform > select.fail { background: red }
```

If you just need the number of empty selects you can use:

```
$('select:has(option[value="none"]:selected)').length
```